# Send just the changes in a transaction from one stream to workspace under a different parent via change palette

Tags: accurev

I am trying to send only the changes in a particular transaction from one stream to workspace under a different parent via change palette. Is there a way to do this?
Right now, When I do a merge in change palette it pulls in all changes until that transaction and draws a merge arrow, I dont want that.

Example:
Let's say at the source stream, file x content is as follows:
abc (line added at txn:5)
def (line added at txn:7)
xyz

At the destination workspace, file x contents:
xyz

I just want to port (txn 7) to make the destination file x content as:
def
xyz

But that doesn't happen. Change Palette pulls in all changes until txn 7.

Let us say I decided to review my merge and select only txn 7 related changes and promote it in my destination. If later for some reason I decide that I need txn 5 ported as well, then this doesn't show up in the change palette, because I already ignored those changes during my previous merge. I don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on stream -> Show history -> Select the transaction you want -> Right click -> Send to -> Change Palette -> Choose destination stream

Comment: You need to use the change package integration if you want this result.  If transaction 5 was a promote with issue 4 and transaction 7 was a promote with issue 8, when you cross promote issue 8, accurev will patch in just the changes for issue 8, transaction 7 and exclude issue 4, transaction 5.